# How to generate a standalone console application from .NET

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, console

EDIT:

I wrote a small cpp program (console application) on MSVS2012 express.
The head of the program is:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;
```

I need to deploy the executable on a machine, where I cannot install 
anything. (I just want to use it as a simple console .exe).
So I need the application to be completely standalone. 
Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Comment: What's inside `stdafx`?

Comment: It's just an empty library added by MSVS (2012 express).

Comment: You state that you are using "some statistical libraries from .NET", but your includes (or imports) don't show any use of those libraries.

Comment: I'm using 'random_shuffle()' from '<algorithm>'

Comment: <algorithm> is not part of .NET. Do you *even need .NET at all?* Try just compiling native, man.

Comment: @mousomer:No. <algorithm> does not contain .NET statistical libraries, it contains algorithms of the C++ standard library.

Comment: So your program has no relation with .NET whatsoever. Please update the title and text.

Comment: The .NET 2.0 runtime should be installed on any existing OS beyond Vista. Can't you do with it?

Comment: you're right. my "client" misread her error messages and I misunderstood the problem. Should I even keep this on?

Comment: This question makes very little sense, beyond the mystery .NET dependency.  If you cannot install anything then you cannot install your program either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by .Net you mean Visual Studio, if you choose the non-dll (i.e. static) runtime libraries from the `C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library` options (/MT or /MTd) then you might just get away with it.
If you use the dll versions, these will need to be on the machine you deploy your app to.

Comment: OK. this is incompatible with /clr (common language runtime support), which means I have no libraries. This needs more configurations?

Comment: None of your includes suggested you want to use CLI. If you do and the box you want to run it on doesn't have the .Net runtime it won't work. Just C++ would work

Comment: interesting...
It's a windows Console application. I was using 
'using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;'

Comment: The first two are .Net. Do you need them? I suggest starting again and just making a C++ console app without CLI support

Comment: @mousomer OK - that needs a new question. Don't forget to show the exact error message you get along with some code

Comment: I tried toying with the compilation flags. It was a disaster. Generated a new project, set no CLI and /MT - and everything is working now. thank.